# I get a timeout when getting a response from a POST HTTP request

Tags: rest, python-requests, httprequest

I am trying to make a POST request to a REST server API. I fail to get back a response message, it times out (only because I set a value).

I can see from the logs of the REST server that the post request has been received and accepted. The REST server logs show `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` and I can see the variable has been changed. So I fail to understand why am I not getting any response message. Here is the code:

```
import requests
url = 'http://192.168.2.1:8080/send'
data = {
  "info": [
    {
      "addr": [
        "remote_control"
      ],
      "type": "BOOL",
      "value": False
    }
  ]
}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.post(url=url, json=data, headers=headers,  timeout=60)
print(response)
```

I have tried to make a POST request using a local REST client and I am able to get a 200 response. But here it times out

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it and get the response by closing the TCP connection. I inserted a key and value pair in the `headers` dictionary

`headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Connection': 'close'}`